# Reverse of git subtree split in certain context

Tags: git, git-subtree

Say, I have repo A which contains folder "foo".
There is also an already inited yet empty repo named B.

Here's what I've done:

1. `git subtree split --prefix foo split-master`
2. `cd B && git pull ../A split-master`
3. `… a bunch of commits …`
4. `git remote add bigA ../A`
5. `git push bigA split-master`

OK, so now I have a splitted branch split-master in A with all that commits from B.
The question is - what is the reverse of split in this context?
How can I reintegrate this split-master into a "big" repo?

Or is this something I actually shouldn't do? I mean, may I missing something?
May be, I should pull everything from repo B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git `subtree` command also has a `merge` subcommand. It follows the syntax:

```
> git subtree merge -P <prefix> <commit>
```

So in your case, running from within repo A you could do

```
> git subtree merge -P foo split-master
```

That would reintegrate the changes made in repo B into the subtree in repo A.

There are some additional options, [check the docs](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt).